# How can I unzip a symbolic link using maven?

Tags: unix, maven, zip, symlink

I have symbolic links that are stored in a zip file.

When unzipping that file using Mac OS system, the symbolic links are maintained (that's to say they are symbolic links and appaer as such).

But, when unzipping them using maven (and specifically [unpack-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) mojo), they appear as simple files.

So, is there a maven plugin preserving that flag ?

Comment: Out of curiousity, how are you creating the zip? Outside of Maven or what?

Comment: @carlspring yeah zip is created out of maven , because maven also don't zip correctly those symlink files (will try to report bug to maven)

Comment: Well, the thing is -- the guys over at Apache won't be able to do much, if they're using Sun's built-in API. If you're using the GNU zip, there are options for handling symlinks in the zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to other answers, it seems like few are the pure Java libraries allowing the unzipping of symlinks.

In such a solution, to have a pure multiplatform build, one does not simply create a module for each os, because it would lead to the classical module arms race, and, more pragmatically, it would not fit in this module lifecycle.

As a consequence, I used my classical scripting-in-maven solution : [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) !

which led to this not so beautiful script

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unzip native code using Groovy</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <providerSelection>${gmaven.provider.version}</providerSelection>
                            <source>
<![CDATA[

def ant = new AntBuilder()

def FOLDERS_TO_EXPLORE = [] /* put here the list of folders in which zip files will be recursively searched */

def unzip(File file) {
    def RUN_ON_WINDOWS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("win")>=0
    if(RUN_ON_WINDOWS) {
        log.debug "unzipping windows style"
        ant.unzip(  src: file, dest:file.parentFile,  overwrite:"true")
    } else {
        def result = ant.exec(outputproperty:"text",
                 errorproperty: "error",
                 resultproperty: "exitValue",
                 dir: file.parent,
                 failonerror: true,
                 executable: "unzip") {
                       arg(value:file.name)
                 }

        if(Integer.parseInt(ant.project.properties.exitValue)!=0) {
            log.error "unable to unzip "+file.name+" exit value is "+ant.project.properties.exitValue
            log.error "=========================================================\noutput\n=========================================================\n"+ant.project.properties.text
            log.error "=========================================================\nerror\n=========================================================\n"+ant.project.properties.error
            fail("unable to unzip "+file)
        } else {
            log.info "unzipped "+file.name
        }
    }
    file.delete()
}

def unzipContentOf(File file) {
    file.eachFileRecurse { 
        if(it.name.toLowerCase().endsWith("zip")) {
            unzip(it)
        }
    }
}

FOLDERS_TO_EXPLORE.each { unzipContentOf(new File(it)) }
]]>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to try out the [truezip-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic links are not implemented on all OS-s. As a matter of fact, after taking a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html), I don't quite think the SDK supports this kind of zip entry at all -- from what I can tell, it's just files and dirs. I wouldn't say it's a limitation of the dependency plugin either, due to that cause.